# To assign a icon to category of custom post type

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have custom post type. I want to assign an icon to each category of custom post post type.
I used category and page icons plugin for that. But it is not working with custom post type.Is there any plugin for custom post type category.

Comment: wordpress.stackexchange.com would be a better choice for that question.

Comment: @MarcinBobowski, plugin recommendation is off-topic over there.

Comment: Oh, than sorry for missinformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) is capable of that. And it is a very fine plugin, well coded, documented and maintained.

In a fast test in my development install.

**Setting the field up:**

> [image: field setup]

**Result in the custom taxonomy screen**

> [image: acf custom tax result]